# pass ajax request in wordpress page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have single.php file in my theme folder and i am using ajax code in this file i have another file in same folder where i am fetching this request but its not working for me here is my jquery written in single.php

```
$na= jQuery.noConflict();
 $na(document).ready(function(){ 
                    $na('nav a').click(function(){
                     var nv=$na(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "_");
                     var pv=nv.toLowerCase();

             $na.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/popupdatapdf.php',
                         data: 'valueMin='+pv,
                        success: function(result){
                                                    alert(result);
                                           }
                                      });


                });
```

Comment: yes the ajax requestr work but the wordpress function not supporting the file and gets the error i tried include file using                      require_once("http://project.test.com/new_test/wp-load.php");         however its still not working any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $('nav a').on('click', function(){
        var nv = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, "_");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/popupdatapdf.php',
            data: {valueMin : nv}
        }).done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
   });
});
```

And open the console to check for errors, also in the network tab to see that the file `popupdatapdf.php` is actually found in the root of the current theme.